# Vector subscript out of range with min and max element

Tags: c++

I am trying to make program which finds max and min element of vector, and and outputs elements in the interval min max, but skips those that were specified in the vector.
For example:
in: 2  6 7
min is 2, max is 7
out: 3 4 5 
But I have error message: vector subscript out of range
The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int size;
    cout << "Enter size:" << endl;
    cin >> size;
    vector <int> vect;
    vect.resize(size);
    for (int j = 0; j < vect.size(); j++)
    {
        cout << "Enter " << j << " element: ";
        cin >> vect[j];
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "Your first vector: " << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < vect.size(); j++)
    {
        cout << vect[j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    int min = *min_element(vect.begin(), vect.end());
    int max = *max_element(vect.begin(), vect.end());

   for(int j = min; j<max;j++)
    {
       if (vect[j] != j)
       {
           cout << j;
}
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `vect[min]` might be >= `vec.size()`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) along with the computed `min` and `max`:

```
for (int i = min + 1; i < max; ++i)
  if (std::find(vect.begin(), vect.end(), i) == vect.end())
    std::cout << i;
```

This is not the most efficient solution (e.g. If you sort the vector, then you don't need to repeatedly call `find`).

Also, be careful when dereferencing the result of `max/min_element` if `vect` is empty. If you do that, you invoke undefined behaviour.

Note that there is a [`minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) that will give you *both* iterators at the same time, which is much nicer.

Comment: Whereas `*min_pos <= *max_pos`, but not necessary `min_pos < max_pos`.

Comment: I want to find them as values, and use in cycle to print the value between the minimum and maximum element of the vector

Comment: @Sevka added a snippet demonstrating that.

Comment: @cigien Thank you, but how to display values ​​in the interval between the minimum and maximum element of the vector, but which do not belong to it
Like a:
vector : 1 3 5
output is: 2 4

Comment: @cigien no problem, maybe I expressed incorrectly. I tried you code and it works but it output wrong
I entered 1 3 5 7
and it outputed 3 5, but had to output 2 4 6
Like elements between min and max but which are not in the vector

Comment: @Sevka oops, that was a type, needed to be `==`, not `!=`. Fixed.

Comment: @cigien if you have time, can you explain how this line works?
if (std::find(vect.begin(), vect.end(), i) == vect.end())

Comment: @Sevka see the linked page in the answer. There are clear explanations there. Feel free to ask if any of those explanations don't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

min and max will return min and max values of the vector. Instead checking with min and max, Check in range[0,vect.size()]

```
for(int j = 0; j<vect.size();j++)
    {
       if (vect[j] !=min && vect[j]!= max)
       {
           cout << j;
       }
    }
```